# How can i export a folder of Firefox Bookmarks into a text file

Tags: windows-7, firefox, bookmarks

I want to clean up my bookmark folders by getting rid of duplicated/links. i have created a program which will import 2 text files which contains a URL like this

File 1:

```
http://www.google/com
http://anime.stackexchange.com/
https://www.fanfiction.net/guidelines/
https://www.fanfiction.net/anime/Magical-Girl-Lyrical-Nanoha/?&srt=1&g1=2&lan=1&r=103&s=2
```

File 2:

```
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56142/why-didnt-dumbledore-just-hunt-voldemort-down
http://anime.stackexchange.com/
http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5650/how-can-the-doctor-be-poisoned
```

the program compares the 2 lists and creates a single master list with duplicate URLs removed.

Now i have a few Backup bookmark folders in Firefox which on occasion i'll bookmark all tabs into a new folder with the date of the backup before i close off tabs or do reset my PC. each folder can have between 1000-2000 bookmarks, sometimes there are a bunch of pages which keep getting bookmarked, ie, i have ~50 pages on the Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha Wiki on different spells, character and terminology which i commonly look back on.

I'd like to know how i can export a bookmark folder so i have a list of URLs similar to what i  use in my program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can think of is to use the export function which will export your bookmarks to a html file and then use grep to extract the urls to a text file.

You could try something like ...

`find * -exec cat {} \;  | grep http | grep -shoP 'http.*?[" >]' > output.txt`

Which would search all files in the directory & output to a txt file
or

`cat bookmark.html | grep http | grep -shoP 'http.*?[" >]' > output.txt`

Which would search a specific file (in this case bookmark.html) for urls & then output to a txt file.

But there are many other ways to go about achieving what you want this is just one example.

Comment: my bad, is this solution for Unix? cause i'm using windows (have edited my question with the tag)

Comment: For windows there is a simple program called urlextactor which can dump urls from html to txt or clipboard. http://www.focalmedia.net/urlextract.html

Comment: I've just tried the program and it works well you can use ctrl to select multiple html files to extract from at once which should for your bookmark folders.

Answer (score 1):

Open the "Library" window (Bookmarks > Manage Bookmarks or Ctrl-Shift-O)

Right click on the wanted bookmarks folder and select "Copy" in the contextual menu.

This copies all URLs from that folder to your clipboard, ready to paste where you want them.